# Mask setup for rust

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, masking

I have created a mask to seperat the surface of a mesh. This is to use some procedural textures to  make rust. The problem i have with it is that the mask doesnt seperate the glossy and difuse so that even the rust has some glossy in it.

I suspect it is the mask iteslf that is causing it. If need be i can upload an image of the whole node setup.[image]